# JS Multiple $(document).ready(function() Merging Issue:

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are two main JS scripts. Both which are WORK as expected independently. One of them is for a menu (which is not in the HTML at the moment) The other is for a div that will change dynamically (in below HTML). 
Both of these use `$(document).ready(function ()` When I put them in seperate files they do not work. Put all functions under the same `$(document).ready(function ()` it still does not work.
If i put them in the same file, as two independent scripts, only the top one will work as expected.
Any Ideas? I'm new to JS and i'm struggling to get my head around how the code is to be laid out.

**JS:**

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    var mainApp = {

        main_fun: function () {
            $('#main-menu').metisMenu();

            $(window).bind("load resize", function () {
                if ($(this).width() < 768) {
                    $('div.sidebar-collapse').addClass('collapse')
                } else {
                    $('div.sidebar-collapse').removeClass('collapse')
                }
            });



        },

        initialization: function () {
            mainApp.main_fun();

        }

    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
      mainApp.main_fun();

    });
  }(jQuery));
```

**SECOND JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var $content = $('.menu-content');
function showContent(type) {
  $($content).hide();
  $('#'+type).show();
}

$('.menu').on('click', '.menu-btn', function(e) {
  showContent(e.currentTarget.hash.slice(1));
  e.preventDefault();

});
  showContent('about');
  });
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src= "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='js/menu/custom.js') }}"></script>

<style>
div{
height: 200px;
width: 50%;
background-color: powderblue;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>


<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#about" class="menu-btn">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact" class="menu-btn">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#cluster" class="menu-btn">cluster</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="about" class="menu-content">This is static - About</div>
<div id="contact" class="menu-content">This is static - Contact</div>
<div id="cluster" class="menu-content">cluster</div>


</body>

</html>
```

[Current result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64IUq.png)

[Expected Result - When I click on the buttons the single div should change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPkcX.png)

Comment: You need to specify what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: There is no intrinsic reason why multiple document ready handlers would cause problems. The problem is more likely to be cross-script dependencies or order of execution. Tell us *what* doesn't work - any errors in the console, for example? Otherwise that's quite a vague statement.

Comment: Please see the edit, there is no errors at the console.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a merged code, try this out:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $content = $('.menu-content');
  function showContent(type) {
    $($content).hide();
    $('#'+type).show();
  }

  $('.menu').on('click', '.menu-btn', function(e) {
    showContent(e.currentTarget.hash.slice(1));
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  showContent('about');
  mainApp.main_fun();
});

(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    var mainApp = {

    main_fun: function () {
        $('#main-menu').metisMenu();

        $(window).bind("load resize", function () {
            if ($(this).width() < 768) {
                $('div.sidebar-collapse').addClass('collapse')
            } else {
                $('div.sidebar-collapse').removeClass('collapse')
            }
        });



    },

    initialization: function () {
        mainApp.main_fun();

    }

}
} (jQuery));
```

Comment: The 'Second JS' is working as expected with this code. However the 'First JS' is not working anymore, the menu's are not populating as expected. its as if the 'mainApp.main_fun();' is not being executed.  These components are working individually.